# Why does a "concurrent" Go GC phase appear to be stop-the-world?

Tags: go, garbage-collection

I am attempting to benchmark the maximum STW GC pause time for different numbers of heap objects. To do this I have written a simple benchmark that pushes and pops messages from a `map`:

```
package main

type message []byte

type channel map[int]message

const (
    windowSize = 200000
    msgCount   = 1000000
)

func mkMessage(n int) message {
    m := make(message, 1024)
    for i := range m {
        m[i] = byte(n)
    }
    return m
}

func pushMsg(c *channel, highID int) {
    lowID := highID - windowSize
    m := mkMessage(highID)
    (*c)[highID] = m
    if lowID >= 0 {
        delete(*c, lowID)
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(channel)
    for i := 0; i < msgCount; i++ {
        pushMsg(&c, i)
    }
}
```

I ran this with [`GODEBUG=gctrace=1`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/), and on my machine the output is:

```
gc 1 @0.004s 2%: 0.007+0.44+0.032 ms clock, 0.029+0.22/0.20/0.28+0.12 ms cpu, 4->4->3 MB, 5 MB goal, 4 P
gc 2 @0.009s 3%: 0.007+0.64+0.042 ms clock, 0.030+0/0.53/0.18+0.17 ms cpu, 7->7->7 MB, 8 MB goal, 4 P
gc 3 @0.019s 1%: 0.007+0.99+0.037 ms clock, 0.031+0/0.13/1.0+0.14 ms cpu, 13->13->13 MB, 14 MB goal, 4 P
gc 4 @0.044s 2%: 0.009+2.3+0.032 ms clock, 0.039+0/2.3/0.30+0.13 ms cpu, 25->25->25 MB, 26 MB goal, 4 P
gc 5 @0.081s 1%: 0.009+9.2+0.082 ms clock, 0.039+0/0.32/9.7+0.32 ms cpu, 49->49->48 MB, 50 MB goal, 4 P
gc 6 @0.162s 0%: 0.020+10+0.078 ms clock, 0.082+0/0.28/11+0.31 ms cpu, 93->93->91 MB, 96 MB goal, 4 P
gc 7 @0.289s 0%: 0.020+27+0.092 ms clock, 0.080+0/0.95/28+0.37 ms cpu, 178->178->173 MB, 182 MB goal, 4 P
gc 8 @0.557s 1%: 0.023+38+0.086 ms clock, 0.092+0/38/10+0.34 ms cpu, 337->339->209 MB, 346 MB goal, 4 P
gc 9 @0.844s 1%: 0.008+40+0.077 ms clock, 0.032+0/5.6/46+0.30 ms cpu, 407->409->211 MB, 418 MB goal, 4 P
gc 10 @1.100s 1%: 0.009+43+0.047 ms clock, 0.036+0/6.6/50+0.19 ms cpu, 411->414->212 MB, 422 MB goal, 4 P
gc 11 @1.378s 1%: 0.008+45+0.093 ms clock, 0.033+0/6.5/52+0.37 ms cpu, 414->417->213 MB, 425 MB goal, 4 P
```

See the link above for documentation on this output.

My version of Go is:

```
$ go version
go version go1.7.1 darwin/amd64
```

From the above results, the longest wall clock STW pause time is `0.093 ms`. Great!

However as a sanity check I also manually timed how long it took to create a new `message` by wrapping `mkMessage` with

```
start := time.Now()
m := mkMessage(highID)
elapsed := time.Since(start)
```

and printed the slowest `elapsed` time. The time I get for this was `38.573036ms`!

I was instantly suspicious because this correlated strongly with the wall clock times in the supposedly concurrent mark/scan phase, and in particular with "idle GC time".

**My question is: why does this supposedly concurrent phase of the GC appear to block the mutator?**

If I force the GC to run at regular intervals, my manually calculated pause times go way down to <1ms, so it appears to be hitting some kind of limit of non-live heap objects. If so, I'm not sure what that limit is, and why it would cause a concurrent phase of the GC to appear to block the mutator.

Comment: Since this is implementation and version specific, if you want a specific answer the go mailing list is probably a more appropriate forum (you should also test this with the current master branch if you haven't done so)

Comment: Took a minute to look at this, and I'm only seeing a rough correlation here, and only with small inputs. The bulk of time in `mkMessage` is spent waiting for an allocation during GC, not in mutating the slice. If I increase the number of pointers an order of magnitude, the time spent in the concurrent phase increases accordingly,  but there's no significant increase in the time taken to allocate or mutate the slices.

Comment: This has a huge map, and there are bugs where they cause pauses. The incremental "mutator assist"--where your code's interrupted to do a small chunk of work, meant to be just microseconds--sometimes wound up scanning the whole map. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-codereviews/kIqdlqEZ47M, https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16432, https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14812, and https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9477. Go tip might work better, or 1.7 if you're on an older version.

Comment: @JimB I will ask in the go mailing list too, thanks for the suggestion. I don't think this is inappropriate for SO because I think it's likely this problem is a characteristic of concurrent STW collectors in general.

When I increase the number of messages an order of magnitude, I *do* see the time to allocate increase: concurrent GC time = 915ms and time to allocate = 824ms.

However the anomalous "background GC time" doesn't seem to correlate over more runs, so I'll remove this from the question.

Comment: @twotwotwo I did originally investigate that, but I'm not sure it's the problem here because the large STW pause appears to happen when allocating with `mkMessage`, not inserting or deleting from the `map`.

Comment: @WillSewell: No, it's not really related to STW collectors in general, because Go isn't using a full STW collector. Like I said, I don't see this behavior on master, so it's likely to be an issue with the go1.7 implementation, https://golang.org/issue/16293 for example

Comment: @WillSewell That's what I'd expect if it were the problem described in those bugs. Mutator GC assists happen on allocation. The existence of the big map is the root cause, but the pause happens at allocation time. Practically speaking the next step (aside from asking the lists) is to try go tip (the latest devel version) to see if the related fixes solve it for you. If they don't, using several smaller maps might be a workaround to reduce max latency.

Answer (score 2):

A concurrent GC pass will typically start at a time when a certain amount of space is available for new allocations.  If that amount of space is adequate to handle all allocations that occur before the pass is complete, the amount of time the application has to wait on the GC will be minimal.  If, however, the quantity of allocations exceeds the space available, new allocation requests will have to wait for the GC to free up more space.

Note that most concurrent GC systems have definite cycles even though programs can run while they are in progress.  The bulk of a GC cycle is spent identifying all of the objects to which references exist, and the only way to identify that no references exist to any individual object is to identify all the references that exist to *everything else*.  Consequently, everything that will get freed by a GC cycle will get freed at once, and nothing will get freed in the interim.

Comment: Let me see if I understand what you are saying. The GC has a certain amount of memory available for new allocations, call this `s`. In my example, as more objects are created, `s` will decrease. When `s` reaches a certain value, a GC will start. If `s` becomes 0, requests to create new objects will block. The requests will only continue once the GC runs again, or more memory is requested from the OS. That makes sense to me, but let me know if I'm not following.

Comment: @WillSewell: That's pretty much it, except that the requests have to wait not just until the GC "runs", but until it completes a cycle.  To find out whether any particular piece of memory can be freed, the system would have to scan through every live object, but a single scan through all live objects would allow the system to identify all of the pieces of memory that can be freed.

Answer (score 0):

To give this more visibility (and detail) than in my comment--the behavior seems to match what's described in [Go bug #9477](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9477) and fixed by [Go changelist 23540](https://go-review.googlesource.com/#/c/23540/).

What happens is, when a thread allocates memory, the garbage collector might give it a little memory-scanning work to do; this is called a "mutator assist." But previously, the work might consist of scanning a map, which would cause a long pause with a big enough map. Consistent with what's reported in the question and comments, the pause would happen when some arbitrary allocation took place--not necessarily while using the map--and would not show up in GC pause stats since it wasn't part of the stop-the-world phase.

The fix made to Go, not yet released as I'm writing, was to limit how much memory a single mutator assist would scan so that it would take no more than about 100 microseconds on typical modern server hardware. If you're encountering this problem I'd recommend trying the latest from the github.com/golang/go repository (or 1.8 once it's out) where the fix is applied. (There's also [another big pause-reduction change](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-dev/Ab1sFeoZg_8/_DaL0E8fAwAJ) in there since 1.7.) If you still have problems and haven't been able to find any explanation, I'd go to golang-nuts.